# displaying custom error messages in stripecheckout.js

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I am using stripecheckout.js for handling payments on my site.

I am configuring the object to be send to the stripe pop up as:

```
      stripeHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: $scope.stripeKey,
                image: 'img/logo.png',
                locale: 'auto',
                panelLabel: 'Pay',
                color: 'black',
                token: handleToken
            });
```

where handleToken is my callback.
Opening the stripe pop up as :

```
    stripeHandler.open({name: //some name,
                        description: //some description,
                        amount: //some amount,
                        currency: //some currency
                        });
```

Now I want to display error custom messages related to expiry and cvv fields.
How do I have to pass these messages inside stripe popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) has a number of [configuration options](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options), but it is not possible to customize the error messages.

If Checkout supports [your language](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#supported-languages), you can use the `data-locale` attribute to force a specific language, or set it to `auto` to use the customer's preferred language automatically.